# FlutterWeb TextFormFields are not accepting Inputs

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

[image]

I tried clearing the state by running `pub run build_runner clean`

but still all the `TextFormField` inside the `Form` are not accepting input(just blank).

I'm using **Flutter 1.9**. `TextField` are also not accepting Input.

I don't have any idea

*Here is my Code*

```
import 'package:flutter_web/material.dart';

class AddContent extends StatefulWidget {
  AddContent({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  _AddContentState createState() => _AddContentState();
}

class _AddContentState extends State<AddContent> {

  final TextStyle mStyleBlack = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'arial', fontSize: 13, color: Colors.black);
  final TextStyle mStyleHintBlack = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'arial', fontSize: 13, color: Colors.black45);
  final TextStyle mStyleWhite = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'arial', fontSize: 13, color: Colors.white70);
  final mStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontFamily: 'arial');
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  TextEditingController _idController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _videoController = TextEditingController();

  List<String> imageFieldList = [''];
  List<TextEditingController> imageFieldControllers = [TextEditingController()];

  int imageCount = 0;
  String dropdownValue = 'none';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final id = TextFormField(
        controller: _idController,
        style: mStyleHintBlack,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Place Id',
          labelStyle: mStyleHintBlack,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            )
          ),
          validator: (val) {
          if(val.isEmpty) {
            return 'Place Id cannot be empty';
          } else {
            print('ID: ${_idController.text}');
            return null;
          }
        },
    );

    final dropdownField = Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Select Category', style: mStyleBlack),
        SizedBox(width: 20),
        DropdownButton<String>(
            value: dropdownValue,
            onChanged: (String newValue) {
              setState(() {
                dropdownValue = newValue;
              });
            },
            items: <String>['none', 'Restaurant', 'Hotel', 'Shop', 'Beauty', 'School', 'Event']
              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value, style: mStyleBlack,),
                );
              })
              .toList(),
        )
      ],
    );

    final videoField = TextFormField(
      obscureText: false,
      controller: _videoController,
      style: mStyleHintBlack,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Youtube Video Link',
        labelStyle: mStyleHintBlack,
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          ),  
        ),
    );

    final submitButton = Material(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      color: Color(0xff01A0C7),
      child: MaterialButton(
        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Text('Add', style: mStyleWhite),
        onPressed: () {
          print('Add Button Pressed!');
          if(_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
          }
        },
      ),
    );

    return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child:  Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  id,
                  Container(height: 3),
                  dropdownField,
                  Container(height: 3),
                  videoField,
                  Container(height: 10),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child:
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 35,
                        child: Text('Images', style: mStyleBlack,),
                      )
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: 
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        height: 35,
                        child: InkWell(
                          child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.green),
                          onTap: () {
                            print('Add Place Tapped!!!');
                            setState(() {
                              imageFieldList.add(''); 
                              imageFieldControllers.add(TextEditingController());
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: 
                      List.generate(imageFieldList.length, (index) => 
                          imageField(index)
                      )
                  ),
                  Container(height: 10), 
                  submitButton
                ],
              ),
            )
    );
  }

  Widget imageField(int index) {
    return Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 9,
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: imageFieldControllers.elementAt(index),
              style: mStyleHintBlack,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Image ${index + 1}',
                labelStyle: mStyleHintBlack,
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  )
                ),
                validator: (val) {
                if(val.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Image cannot be empty';
                } else {
                  print('Image ${index + 1}: ${imageFieldControllers.elementAt(index).text}');
                  return null;
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: (index > 0)? 
              Container(
                child: InkWell(
                  child: Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
                  onTap: () {
                    print('Remove Image');
                    setState(() {
                     imageFieldList.removeAt(index); 
                     imageFieldControllers.removeAt(index);
                    });
                  },
                )
              ):
              Container()
          )
        ],
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Changes were made from the current update which prevents existing projects from working after upgrading to the latest Flutter Version. Solved it by following the instructions in latest Flutter 1.9 docs https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently flutter team added [new way](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web) for building flutter web applications, and there is no problem with `TextField`. Although there is one caveat now - it only works on master channel.

Answer (score 0):

follow this step

1. `flutter channel master` 2. `flutter upgrade` 3. `flutter config --enable-web`

   4. *cd into project directory* 5. `flutter create` . 6. `flutter run -d chrome`